# Newline in equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

The code looks something like:

```
        $$  
        If \ abs(dx) = abs(dy) \  then \\
            step = abs(dx)\\
        else \\
            step = abs(dy)\\
        $$
```

I want the '\\' to behave as in normal way (newline) but it does not display a newline.

Thanks

Comment: I think the [`algorithms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) package might be better suited for your needs than simple mathmode.

Comment: I use the `lstlisting`-package for advanced code listing. the [documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) is quite helpful.

Comment: Something else, the use of `$$…$$` for equations is deprecated in LaTeX. Use `\[…\]` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the comments above that `algorithms`, `algorithmic` or `lstlisting` packages are probably best for this kind of work, but in the case you want to only do something fairly simple, and you don't want to learn new package, you can use some of the `amsmath` environments, for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\newcommand\If{\text{If }}
\newcommand\Then{\text{ then }}
\newcommand\Else{\text{else }}
\DeclareMathOperator\abs{abs}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
   &\If & \abs(dx) &= \abs(dy) && \Then \\
   && step &= \abs(dx) \\
   &\Else \\
   && step &= \abs(dy)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

It will look like this:

[image]